# Moneris e-commerce checklist before setting up a site?

Tags: ecommerce

Apparently, according to their customer service, I can't sign up with Moneris for payment processing unless my website's up and running. To that effect, they've provided a checklist of items I need before I can sign up. Some of these items are:

- Privacy Policy
- SSL 128 bit
- Full description of products

The issue is that this client's website is highly confidential as it's in the process of getting trademarks and other intellectual property rights secured. So I can't put up a half finished site without risk of prematurely putting up the client's data publicly.

How do I work around this with Moneris?

Comment: Have you asked *them*? This isn't exactly a unique situation. They should have some sort of policy in place for dealing with it.

Comment: No its not and they should be custom to NDA agreements.

Comment: Su': I didn't mention because I thought it would be blatantly obvious. But yes, I took up my beef with them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi TechWire – Great question. We frequently work with Merchants to get their accounts up and running while they are still developing their sites.

Typically during this time, merchants won’t be able to access the proceeds of any transactions they process - But this usually isn't a problem because most merchants will only process small test transactions to make sure their integration is working properly prior to launch.

Once the merchant has launched publicly, they simply let us know where we can go to validate the site is fully compliant and then we’ll start the process to release the funds for any of their test transactions. It’s pretty simple and doesn't take long.

Also, just a quick note: Your customer will need to set-up their Merchant Account with us directly since it’s them who we’ll have the ongoing relationship with. When they are ready to get started, they can speak to a member of our Sales Team at 1-866-473-8707.

Hope this answers your questions? If not, just let us know.

Comment: I'm impressed by the fact that I've actually got a response from Moneris! I will let my client know about this and I'm sure he'll be extremely pleased. Thank you!